# Random samples from a uniform distribution over [0, 1]

Tags: python, numpy, random, probability

We all know and love the `numpy` function `random.rand`, which "create[s] an array of the given shape and propagate[s] it with random samples from a uniform distribution over `[0, 1)`":

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.rand(3,2)
array([[ 0.14022471,  0.96360618],  #random
       [ 0.37601032,  0.25528411],  #random
       [ 0.49313049,  0.94909878]]) #random
```

What are my options if I want random samples from a uniform distribution over `[0, 1]`?  ***Note the subtle difference:*** The `numpy` function excludes `1`; my desired function *includes* `1`.

Comment: In float64, there is exactly 1 in 2^52 chance for a perfect 1 to happen, if it were to be included. My question is, does it really matter?

Comment: @metatoaster i don't think it does.  that said, i'm replicating results in a published paper, and, should my results be subtly different from the ones reported, i don't want this to be the reason.

Comment: You might want to have a read about [double precision floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Double-precision_examples) and specifically about the examples, and generate your own bit representation of the range of numbers you need using [`random.getrandbits`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.getrandbits), or maybe verify that the default implementation [`random.random`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.random) provides this.

Comment: Also, if you are replicating the paper, you might want to figure out whether it used a Mersenne Twister (native python implementation) or an actual true random number generator.

Comment: @metatoaster then again, there are probably a thousand other differences of this magnitude between what i'm doing and what those authors did.  for example, i highly doubt they used python.

Comment: Haha, yeah. That's always a problem with trying to replicate experimental results.

Comment: I previously tried to answer to your question (see below) but like the others, I strongly think you shouldn't care about this very tiny difference. I also thought that if such a difference matters for you, are you aware about denormalized floats https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number ? In two words, the density of encoded float numbers isn't uniform everywhere in [0,1]. I don't know exactly how random numbers are generated by Numpy but such a fact could disturb you as well.

Comment: Just to be difficult: why do you care specifically about `1.0` being excluded?  There are around 2^62 distinct double-precision floats in the range `[0.0, 1.0]`. `random.rand` can already only generate a tiny fraction of those - about 1 in 500. (There are 2^53 possible outputs from `random.rand`.) One more missing possible output value really isn't going to make much difference.  IOW, just use the `[0, 1)` range; it's going to be statistically indistinguishable from an artifically-created `[0, 1]` range random.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you can build the greatest number less than 1 with something like:

```
import struct
m = struct.unpack("d",struct.pack("Q",eval("0b00" + "1"*9 + "0" + "1"*52)))[0]
```

which seems to be:

```
m = struct.unpack("d",'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xef?')[0]
```

(according to the IEEE 754 standard). Have a look at:

```
from decimal import Decimal
Decimal(m)
```

which prints:

```
Decimal('0.99999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875')
```

Then, just divide your `np.random.rand` by this value and you should have what you are looking for.

Comment: Intuitively, rounding after division will result in some other float number being excluded out of that possible range, wouldn't it? Still, brilliantly technically correct.

Comment: i guess then also i'd have to confirm that `numpy.random.rand` actually includes this largest possible number less than one?

Comment: A simpler method to get the greatest floating point number less than 1 is `numpy.nextafter(1.0, 0)`.

Comment: Yes, this looks sure to make matters worse.

Comment: @Baruchel: if you're assuming IEEE 754, you might as well just go with `m = 1 - 2**-53` and avoid all the messing about with `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

I previously answered to your question (see my other answer); I also posted a comment. As I said in my comment, I don't really believe you should care about the little difference; but maybe you can achieve what you want like that.

Get a random INTEGER corresponding to the sequences of bit of a IEEE 754 number in [1,2] **rather than [0,1] because of denormalized numbers**; convert the bits to a float IEEE 754 number; then substract 1. This will work because all numbers in [1,2] in IEEE 754 are contiguous.

```
# sequence of bit for 1.0
>>> eval("0b00" + "1"*10 + "0"*51 + "0")
4607182418800017408

# sequence of bit for first number after 2.0
>>> eval("0b01" + "0"*10 + "0"*51 + "1")
4611686018427387905

>>> struct.unpack("d",struct.pack("Q",np.random.randint(4607182418800017408,4611686018427387905)))[0]-1
0.9349236864324189
```

You should be able to get 0 as well as 1. However I am not sure that integer numbers between two large integer values will be exactly uniform...

A cleaner function could be:

```
from struct import pack, unpack
import numpy as np

def myrand():
  a = unpack("Q",pack("d",1.0))[0]               # 1.0
  b = unpack("Q",pack("d",np.nextafter(2,3)))[0] # 2.000000000000000444
  return unpack("d",pack("Q",np.random.randint(a,b)))[0]-1
```

But again, this is more a proof of concept than everything else.